# Error 500 INSERT PDO with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

My recordDate.php:

```
<?php
     $host = "localhost";
     $userDB = "user";
     $passwordDB = "0000";
     $database = "myDatabase";

     $getUser = $_POST['user'];

     $now = date("h:i:s");

     $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database, $userDB, $passwordDB);
     $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT into log (userLog,dateLog) VALUES (:userLog,:dateLog)");
     $stmt->bindParam(':userLog', $getUser);
     $stmt->bindParam(':dateLog', $now);
     $stmt->execute();
?>
```

I don't understand because it shows `500 Internal Server Error` with this ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "recordDate.php",
        data: "user="+user,
});
```

Data connecion are fine and work fine with SELECT.
Anybody help me?

Comment: use data in ajax like `data : {user:user}`

Comment: its an internal server error, debug the PHP, turn on error reporting and check the network tab for errors, there is nothing wrong with the AJAX script, also check for `user` if its not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call should be formatted like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "recordDate.php",
    data: {user: user}, // you need to pass an object here
    sucess: function() {},
    error: function() {}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using your code and it looks fine on my computer.

Please check your error log. If you don't know what is  your error log path, create a file with `<?php phpinfo();?>` and search for "error_log"
or include the following code in your file.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Check:

1. Database name
2. Database user
3. Database password
4. Database hostname
5. Columns name

500 Internal Server Error  is an error from your PHP